# running a new query for each record pulled from another query

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this query

```
try
{
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query3="SELECT * FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result3 = $pdo->query($query3);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to pull rides.';
include 'output.html.php';
}
```

the results of which are displayed here

```
<?php foreach ($result3 as $row3): ?>

<h2 style="display:inline;"><?php echo $row3['name']; ?></h2><h3 style="display:inline;"> - <?php echo $row3['type']; ?></h3> 
<h3>Manufactured by <?php echo $row3['make']; ?>, Opened <?php echo $row3['opened']; ?> </h3>
<br>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My problem is this. I have multiple photos of each ride, the URLs of which are stored in the table tpf_images. The connecting column is ride_id, found in both tpf_rides and tpf_images. How do I run a query so that during the above foreach loop it will also pull all connected image URLs for each ride that can then be displayed as part of the loop?

Please be as clear as possible I am still learning PHP!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for mysql.

So your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tpf_rides
LEFT JOIN tpf_images
ON tpf_rides.ride_id=tpf_images.ride_id 
WHERE park_id = $park_id
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

Comment: This has almost worked perfectly. The correct images are matching to the correct rides. The problem is it is duplicating each ride in the list, once for every picture. like this: Oblivion - Roller Coaster - Dive
Manufactured by Bolliger & Mabillard, Opened 1998
/images/alton towers/altontest1.jpg test

Oblivion - Roller Coaster - Dive
Manufactured by Bolliger & Mabillard, Opened 1998
/images/alton towers/altontest2.jpg testOblivion - Roller Coaster - Dive
Manufactured by Bolliger & Mabillard, Opened 1998
/images/alton towers/altontest3.jpg test  how can I make it so each ride appears once?

Comment: If it helps this is the new foreach query I'm using, it includes echo URL, which is the column in tpf_images that contains the image link. Like I said before this foreach loop is showing duplicate ride names and info for every picture connected with the ride.   <?php foreach ($result2 as $row2): ?>

<h2 style="display:inline;"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></h2><h3 style="display:inline;"> - <?php echo $row2['type']; ?></h3> 
<h3>Manufactured by <?php echo $row2['make']; ?>, Opened <?php echo $row2['opened']; ?> </h3>
<img border="0" src="<?php echo $row2['url']; ?>" >
<br>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: you could change foreach loop to: if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //Do your thing
   } } And afterwards create array $already_in = array(); before while cycle and inside while you could check if(in_array($row2['name'],$already_in){ //do nothing } else { $already_in[] = $row2['name']; echo $row2['name']; }